# c# draw lines with dragging

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, drawing, gdi+

How to draw a line like the windows Paint does, single click for a fixed first point, and the second point (and the line) moves with mouse, another click fixes the line.

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseMove(e);
    // Create the graphics object
    Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
    // Create the pen that will draw the line
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Navy);
    // Create the pen that will erase the line
    Pen erase = new Pen(Color.White);
    g.DrawLine(erase, 0, 0, x, y);
    // Save the mouse coordinates
    x = e.X; y = e.Y;
    g.DrawLine(p, 0, 0, x, y);
}
```

The clicking event part is fine, but with this method above, the erase line is actually white lines, which overlaps on other background image and previously plotted blue lines.

Is there a more manageable way to make it happen? Thanks

Comment: are you looking to save the resulting image afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any drawing on the form client area should be implemented in the **OnPaint** event to avoid any strange effects.
Consider the following code fragment:

```
Point Latest { get; set; }

List<Point> _points = new List<Point>(); 

protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseMove(e);

    // Save the mouse coordinates
    Latest = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

    // Force to invalidate the form client area and immediately redraw itself. 
    Refresh();
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var g = e.Graphics;
    base.OnPaint(e);

    if (_points.Count > 0)
    {
        var pen = new Pen(Color.Navy);
        var pt = _points[0];
        for(var i=1; _points.Count > i; i++)
        {
            var next = _points[i];
            g.DrawLine(pen, pt, next);
            pt = next;
        }

        g.DrawLine(pen, pt, Latest);
    }
}

private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Latest = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    _points.Add(Latest);
    Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it. It is quite neat, but with the Refresh method, it keeps no previous lines. Once I start a new line drawing, the previous one will be gone. Is there a way to keep all previous lines?

Comment: Then you can save all the previous points from the **OnClick()** event in a list and draw then from the **OnPaint()**.

Comment: Please, see the updated code fragment above in the answer.

Comment: To eliminate the flickering effect it is necessary to set **DoubleBuffered** property on the form to **True**.

Comment: what is this OnPaint? When I look at events e.g. on a form, I see it gets called e.g. Form1_Paint

Comment: @barlop: The **OnPaint()** is overridible method of the Form class. According the description it raises the _Paint_ event. The Visual Studio Form Designer just helps you to add the _Paint_ event handler. So you can use any of these options.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to erase the lines by drawing on top of them. You'll be better off if you draw to an off-screen buffer and on each draw call paint that bitmap to the control. That way you'll get flicker-free graphics and a clean line that works just the way you want it to.

Take a look at [this forum post](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/67275-the-wonders-of-systemdrawinggraphics/) for a good explanation of how you should use the `Graphics` class and do drawing in general. There's also a good example program in the end of the post. I suggest you to take a look at that source code after going through the instructions.